cannot center images in grid in css
I've been trying to complete this challenge project for Web Dev on Codecademy and I'm stuck on trying to center images in a grid. I've tried to use justify-content and justify-items in just about every selector within the grid and the grid container itself and cannot figure out what is wrong.


/* Services */

.services-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.services {
  display: flex;
}

.image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'img-1 img-2' 'img-3 img-4';
  padding: .5rem;
  justify-items: center;
}

.image-container h3 {
  background-color: #c4a77d;
  color: #313715;
  /* padding: 2rem 0; */
  font-size: 1.45rem;
}

.img-1,
.img-2,
.img-3,
.img-4 {
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: #c4a77d;
  opacity: .75;
  align-content: center;
}

.services img {
  border: 2px solid #313715;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  justify-items: center;
}

.services h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
  <h2 class="services-title">Our Services</h2>
  <div class="services" id="services">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="img-1">
        <h3>Herbal Mixes</h3>
        <img src="img-1" alt="alt">
      </div>
      <div class="img-2">
        <h3>Spelled Candles</h3>
        <img src="img-2" alt="alt">
      </div>
      <div class="img-3">
        <h3>Herbal Tinctures</h3>
        <img src="img-3" alt="alt">
      </div>
      <div class="img-4">
        <h3>Organic Herbs</h3>
        <img src="img-4" alt="alt">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




Is all that code really needed to show your problem? Please see [ask], then revise to reduce and simplify, and replace your image paths with placeholders. Also take the [tour].

Indeed, we don't want your whole codebase, just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Children of the element display: grid don't inherit this property. So your grid layout is telling the child elements to center align, but it's not telling it's "grandchildren" to center align as well as the child elements. The child elements themselves will default to display: block, which is why their child elements aren't center aligned.

The image-container is not centered for a start. Fix that and go from there.

I hope you are talking about images in the section "Our Services." So if that is so then change this CSS code only like below:
.img-1,
.img-2,
.img-3,
.img-4 {
    margin: 1%;
    background-color: #c4a77d;
    opacity: .75;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

Hope this helps!
